# Como testar se uma cadeia de caracteres é um número na linguagem C?

Tags: c, array, char, caracteres, números

Sou iniciante na programação.

Estou realizando um exercício no qual eu devo determinar se uma cadeia de caracteres é um número, considerando que o usuário pode escrever qualquer coisa como entrada. Então criei a função abaixo. Eu só posso usar a biblioteca padrão. Estou tentando usar o mínimo de variáveis possível.

Alguém poderia avaliar?

```
int isNumber(char input[], int input_size){

int i;

//Elimina cadeia com caracteres não numéricos
for(i = 1; i < input_size; i++)
{
    if(input[i-1] != '0' && input[i-1] != '1' &&
       input[i-1] != '2' && input[i-1] != '3' &&
       input[i-1] != '4' && input[i-1] != '5' &&
       input[i-1] != '6' && input[i-1] != '7' &&
       input[i-1] != '8' && input[i-1] != '9' &&
       input[i-1] != '.' && input[i-1] != ',' &&
       input[i-1] != ' ' && input[i-1] != '-' &&
       input[i-1] != '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
}

//Elimina cadeia que só possui espaços e caracteres nulos
for(i = 1; i < input_size; i++){
    if(input[i-1] != ' ' && input[i-1] != '\0'){
        break;
    }
}
if(i >= input_size){
    return 0;
}

//Elimina cadeia com mais de um ponto ou vírgula
for(i = 1; i < input_size; i++){
    if(input[i-1] == '.' || input[i-1] == ','){
        for(i++; i < input_size; i++){
            if(input[i-1] == '.' || input[i-1] == ','){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

//Elimina cadeia com mais de um sinal de menos
for(i = 1; i < input_size; i++){
    if(input[i-1] == '-'){
        for(i++; i < input_size; i++){
            if(input[i-1] == '-'){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

//Elimina cadeia com dois números separados por espaço
for(i = 2; i < input_size; i++){
    if(input[i-2] != ' ' &&
       input[i-2] != '\0' &&
       input[i-1] == ' ' &&
       input[i] != ' ' &&
       input[i] != '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
}

//Elimina cadeia com dois números separados por sinal de menos
for(i = 2; i < input_size; i++){
    if(input[i-2] != ' ' &&
       input[i-2] != '\0' &&
       input[i-1] == '-' &&
       input[i] != ' ' &&
       input[i] != '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
}

//Elimina cadeia terminada em sinal de menos
for(i = input_size; i > 0; i--){
    if(input[i-0] != '\0' && input[i-0] != ' ' && input[i-0] == '-'){
        return 0;
    }
}

//Elimina cadeia que somente tem ponto, vírgula ou sinal de menos
if((input[0] == '.' || input[0] == ',' || input[0] == '-') && (input[1] == ' ' || input[1] == '\0')){
    return 0;
}
for(i = 2; i < input_size; i++){
    if((input[i-2] == ' ' || input[i-2] == '\0') &&
       (input[i-1] == '.' || input[i-1] == ',' || input[i-1] == '-') &&
       (input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\0')){
        return 0;
    }
}

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de percorrer a sequência de caracteres várias vezes procurando por propriedades específicas, é melhor examinar uma vez só, considerando as propriedades de um número bem formado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FLAG_DIGITO_ENCONTRADO 1

int
eh_numero(const char * entrada) {
    unsigned int flags = 0;
    // um número pode ter uma quantidade arbitrária de espaços antes dele
    while (*entrada == ' ') entrada ++;
    // seguido, opcionalmente, de um único sinal de menos
    if (*entrada == '-') entrada ++;
    // seguido de zero ou mais dígitos
    while (*entrada >= '0' && *entrada <= '9') {
        flags |= FLAG_DIGITO_ENCONTRADO;
        entrada ++;
    }
    // se encontrou pelo menos um dígito, o número pode terminar aqui
    if ((flags & FLAG_DIGITO_ENCONTRADO) && *entrada == '\0')
        return 1;
    // senão, vai ter que encontrar um separador decimal
    if (*entrada == '.' || *entrada == ',') entrada ++;
    // Se não houver dígitos antes da vírgula/ponto, precisa de
    // pelo menos um depois do ponto
    if (!(flags & FLAG_DIGITO_ENCONTRADO) && (*entrada < '0' || *entrada > '9'))
        return 0;
    // se houver, pode haver mais zero ou mais dígitos depois do ponto
    while (*entrada >= '0' && *entrada <= '9') entrada ++;

    // finalmente, temos que ter chegado ao fim da sequência, ou
    // ela não é um número
    return (*entrada == '\0');
}

// main para efetuar alguns testes
#define VERIFIQUE(N) printf("A sequência " N " %sé um numero válido\n",\
    eh_numero(N) ? "" : "não ")
int
main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    VERIFIQUE("0");
    VERIFIQUE("         -2.5");
    VERIFIQUE("1.");
    VERIFIQUE(",25");
    VERIFIQUE("3..");
    VERIFIQUE("+1");
    VERIFIQUE("--8");
    VERIFIQUE(",");
    VERIFIQUE("3A");

    return 0;
}
```

Note que eu usei um `unsigned int` para guardar flags binárias. No caso, só precisei de uma (para guardar contra o caso de não haver dígitos nem antes, nem depois da vírgula), mas poderia haver mais caso quiséssemos converter o número em `float`, por exemplo. Neste caso, a segunda flag seria 2, a terceira 4, a quarta 8, e por assim em diante. Usa-se disjunção bit-a-bit (`|`) para ligar a flag, e conjunção bit-a-bit (`&`) para testar se está ligada. Podia substituir por uma variável simples neste caso, mas acho que vale a pena só para lembrar as pessoas desta possibilidade.

O resultado dos testes:

```
$ cc -o so201793 so201793.c -Wall

$ ./so201793
A sequência 0 é um numero válido
A sequência          -2.5 é um numero válido
A sequência 1. é um numero válido
A sequência ,25 é um numero válido
A sequência 3.. não é um numero válido
A sequência +1 não é um numero válido
A sequência --8 não é um numero válido
A sequência , não é um numero válido
A sequência 3A não é um numero válido

$
```

Comment: Resposta impecável. Infelizmente, tem alguns comandos/conceitos que ainda não vi nas aulas de programação em C. Então fiz um código diferente, mas com essa mesma abordagem de percorrer a cadeia uma única vez. Obrigado de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 1):

Ve se é isso q vc queria.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int IsNumber( char input[] )
{
    register int i;
    int flagVirgula = 0;

    for(i = 0; input[i]; i++)
    {
        if( !i && !(input[i] - '-') )//Numero negativo
            continue;

        if( (!(input[i] - ',') || !(input[i] - '.')) && !flagVirgula )//só pode posuir uma virgula ou ponto
        {
            flagVirgula = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if( (!(input[i] - ',') || !(input[i] - '.')) )//segunda virgula
            return 0;

        if( (input[i] - '0') < 0 || (input[i] - '0') > 9 )
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main()
{   
    char nome[50];

    while(1)
    {
        gets(nome);

        printf("%s\n", IsNumber(nome) ? "E um numero." : "Nao e um numero.");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Não está dando a saída exata que eu queria. Mas me fez perceber que, ao me forçar a usar o mínimo de variáveis possíveis, estou complicando demais a lógica do meu código e dificultando a legibilidade. Obrigado.

Comment: @CL27 Não se preocupe com o número de variáveis do seu código: O compilador simplificará muitas coisas para melhorar o desempenho do seu programa, de qualquer maneira. Tente usar o número de variáveis que você achar necessário, e seja descritivo quando criar uma variável.

Comment: mas se preocupar em simplificar sim - esse código está bem melhor que o apresentado na questão - em particular pro só percorrer a sequencia uma vez, e não com um  loop para cada caso.  Em sistemas mais complexos, se for necessário um loop para cada caso, faça cada loop ter uma função própria - senão fica bem difícil manter controle.

Comment: e o essencial da resposta,q eu está certo aqui, é qeu em C se pode comparar caracteres diretamente pelo código - então a expressão `( (input[i] - '0') < 0 || (input[i] - '0') > 9 )` é  a que faz realmente toda a diferennça em vez de se comparar o caractere com cada dígito de forma hard-coded.